# Aren't girls allowed to have twin-braid hairstyle?

Tags: scripture, women

I came across a facebook post that today schools instruct girl students to have twin braid hairstyle due to lack of knowledge in Sastras, but actually as per Sastras it is prohibited. Is it true? If yes, provide along with source from any scriptures.

Comment: This is cultural issue.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar having lose hair also cultural?

Comment: No , In some cases not.

Comment: Is [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/95/5a/2b955a09032b0501854b942b95ea86f0.jpg) the hairstyle u are talking about?

Comment: @Rickross yes, like that only.

Comment: two tail ponytail braid